# Querying a list in Firebase Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore database in my project. I have a data structure as below:

- users (Collection)

  - user1 (document)

    - followingPeople (array)

      - 0

        - person0
      - 1

        - person1
      - 2

        - person2
      - 3

        - person3
  - user2 (document)

    - followingPeople (array)

      - 0

        - person0
      - 1

        - person1

I need to write a query which finds the users with a specific person in the following people part of the document fields.

For example if I query for the users which following person0 both user1 and user2 will be returned according to my example above.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the `followingPeople` in an array is an anti-pattern. Please read the [Firestore documentation on working with arrays, lists and sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) for a better approach.

```
followingPeople: {
    "person0": true,
    "person1": true,
    "person2": true
}
```

I'd also recommend reading my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value. While it was written for the Firebase Realtime Database, the same logic applies here.